# Paypal IPN cannot send to my MVC 4 controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

I try to get IPN message from my MVC Controller action but IPN cannot send to my action controller

The following is my controller action :

```
                string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);

                //Set values for the request back
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);
                string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);
                strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate";
                req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

                //for proxy
                //Dim proxy As New WebProxy(New System.Uri("http://url:port#"))
                //req.Proxy = proxy

                //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
                StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
                streamOut.Write(strRequest);
                streamOut.Close();
                StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                streamIn.Close();

                if (strResponse == "VERIFIED") {
                    //check the payment_status is Completed
                    //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                    //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                    //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                    //process payment
                } else if (strResponse == "INVALID") {
                    //log for manual investigation
                } else {
                    //Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
                }
```

The following is paypal information I used :

```
<add key="paypalAccount"    value="abc@abc.com" />
<add key="PayPalSubmitUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
<add key="PDTToken" value="asdfwlfti2Rc_Kskwsdfc7uK26FmT1pdAkhSdLb8FvS2kQ-ZQp6VoF2SqYem"/>
<add key="FromMail" value="myat@abc.com"/>
<add key="return_Url" value="http://testing/Purchase/PayPalResult"/>
<add key="cancel_return" value="http://testing/Purchase/Purchase"/>
<add key="notify_url" value="http://testing/Purchase/PayPalPaymentNotification"/>
<add key="Test_Live" value="live"/>
<add key="BCC" value="myat@abc.com"/>
```

But in paypal IPN message is still retrying and I didn't receive anything 
I notice that *HttpContext.Request.ContentLength* is always 0 and response status for paypal is always is INVALID 
So please advice me what should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Please add your controller signature.

Comment: I am new to MVC, please advice what is controller signature?

Comment: No problem - the controller method name and parameters...

Answer (score 1):

This is my full action to get IPN message

```
    public ActionResult PayPalPaymentNotification()
    {
        string strLog = "";
        string currentTime = "";


        currentTime = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + "|" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString();

        strLog = "Insert into CPLog(Log,LogTime) values('Start IPN request','" + currentTime + "')";
        InsertData(strLog);
        string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);
        strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //for proxy
        //Dim proxy As New WebProxy(New System.Uri("http://url:port#"))
        //req.Proxy = proxy

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            //check the payment_status is Completed
            //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            //process payment
            currentTime = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + "|" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString();

            strLog = "Insert into CPLog(Log,LogTime) values('Status - Verified','" + currentTime + "')";
            InsertData(strLog);
        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
            currentTime = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + "|" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString();

            strLog = "Insert into CPLog(Log,LogTime) values('Status - Invalid','" + currentTime + "')";
            InsertData(strLog);
        }
        else
        {
            //Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
        }
        currentTime = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + "|" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds.ToString();

        strLog = "Insert into CPLog(Log,LogTime) values('Finish IPN Request','" + currentTime + "')";
        InsertData(strLog);
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return URL isn't right - the message can never be returned.

Add `[AllowAnonymous]` above the controller action.

Comment: yes, I put really URL and I already tested it in Browsers. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are you expecting Paypal to return to this url - http://testing/Purchase/PayPalResult?

Comment: No I just change my real URL, this is my real one http://27.54.48.41/Purchase/PayPalPaymentNotification

Comment: I just checked it and was reidrected to a login - the controller should allow anonymous access.

Comment: Have you got [AllowAnonymous] above the controller action?

Comment: I don't use action filter then I also need to add [AllowAnonymous] also?

Comment: It looks like your controller is only for authenticated users - the PayPal call isn't authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal needs to know the URL of your listener service that indicates where the IPNs need to go. You must review the IPN Notification section on your Paypal account and set the URL. 
For this you can review the following section: [Paypal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) and set the notifications URL.

After that you must have a payment notification to recieve.
My recomendation is first use the [Paypal developer section](https://developer.paypal.com) with Sandbox whis is king of fake account that you can use for testing this application.